Android jetpack compose to bitmap
I'm trying write compose to bitmap.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#composable-to-bitmap
Text("Hello $name!",
     modifier = Modifier
         .drawWithContent {
             graphicsLayer.record {
                 this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
             }
             drawLayer(graphicsLayer)
         },
)
IconButton({
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
          mBitmap = graphicsLayer.toImageBitmap()
          showDialog = true
    }
 } ...

On Samsung SM-A720F (Android 8) I got:

Like horizontal synchronization failure.
On other smartphones and emulator I got the corrent bitmap:

How to fix this bug on Samsung SM-A720F?

That probably will be tricky to track down. I could not reproduce the issue on my phone. I would suggest that you investigate this issue further. Does it also happen when you display your image somewhere else instead of in the dialog? Does it work correctly when using the old APIs to capture a Composable? Check out this library: https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable/tree/957d528d029b9ce5fbe16b963c4ddc0656106fc2 Until version 2.1, it used the old APIs. Starting from version 3.0.0, it uses the new APIs. Try both versions and see if the older version fixes the problem on your Samsung.

I made something like the Toy Paint app. I've saved pictures in jpeg files and got that glitch on Samsung SM-A720F . https://github.com/s3va/My_Paint . Dialog is only for MRE. So it happen not only in the Dialog. I haven't tried the old APIs to capture a Composable yet.

This method with Picture() works fine on Samsung SM-A720F. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77597340/11798617
